# Stray line feed character at the end of the bash complete output

Tags: autocomplete

So I routinely push applications to background and switch among them. I realized that fg doesn't have a tab complete defined.

So I thought I can put together a tab complete for fg quickly with the suggestions coming from the jobs command. I didn't check if something like this exists online already, cause this seemed like a fun project to build. Here's my code so far:

```
job(){
  readarray COMPREPLY < <(jobs -l)
  for i in "${!COMPREPLY[@]}"; do
      printf -v pad %*s -$COLUMNS "${COMPREPLY[i]}"
      COMPREPLY[i]="%"${pad//[][]}
  done
}
```

The problem is that at the end of each suggestion there's a stray linefeed character(^j) showing up eg:

> %1  53967 Stopped                 vim^J
>
> %2  54257 Stopped             python^J
>
> %3  54499 Stopped (signal)        nano^J
>
> %4- 42270 Stopped    vim ~/.bashrc^J
>
> %5+ 47434 Stopped                 vim ~/.bashrc^J

Comment: Change `readarray` to `readarray -t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help mapfile` synonym of readarray:

> Options:
>         -t        Remove a trailing DELIM from each line read (default newline)

Add that option to your readarray call to trim the trailing new lines off.